# How can we track a same object/person in video after he moves out and in from/to the frame?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

The problem is that ID will lost or interchange after the person moves out of the frame and comes back to the frame(will assigned a new ID) but I want the same ID.

I have tried pyimagesearch(simple object tracking) which was done using centriod/euclidean distance method

Comment: Please share the code you are trying to make work...

Comment: This is an unsolved problem. Take a look at the relevant scientific literature.

Comment: The problem known as "Person Re-Identification" in literature (single-camera or multi-camera tasks)

Comment: The only way is to maintain a database of the object/person being tracked, register with database every time the object re-appears and use the same id.